# Defining a measure as an integral of a positive bounded measurable function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a question about the way [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment_measure#cite_note-stoyan1995stochastic-3) wikipedia article defines the factorial moment measure.

> The $n$th factorial moment measure or $n$th order factorial moment measure is defined as:
> $$
> M^{(n)}\left(B_{1} \times \cdots \times B_{n}\right)=E\left[N^{(n)}\left(B_{1} \times \cdots \times B_{n}\right)\right]
> $$
> where the $E$ denotes the expectation (operator) of the point process $N$. In other words, the n-th factorial moment measure is the expectation of the n th factorial power of some point process.
> The $n$th factorial moment measure of a point process $N$ is equivalently defined ${ }^{[3]}$ by:
> $$
> \int_{\mathbf{R}^{n d}} f\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) M^{(n)}\left(d x_{1}, \ldots, d x_{n}\right)=E\left[\sum_{\left(x_{1} \neq \ldots \neq x_{n}\right) \in N} f\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)\right]
> $$ as opposed to the moment measure.

In what sense does $$\int_{\mathbf{R}^{n d}} f\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) M^{(n)}\left(d x_{1}, \ldots, d x_{n}\right)=E\left[\sum_{\left(x_{1} \neq \ldots \neq x_{n}\right) \in N} f\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)\right]$$ define $M^{(n)}$? Is there a source for measures being defined this way?